# Jquery mouseover / mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure what to search for exactly but here is my issue.

```
<script>
    function Gbox () {
        var hide = document.getElementById('g-box').style.display = "none";

    }
    Gbox();
    $("#g-plus").mouseover(function () {
        $("#g-box").show(400);  
    });
    $("#g-plus").mouseleave(function () {
        $("#g-box").hide(400);  
    });

</script>
```

Said Jquery works without a problem.

Only issue is that if i hover in and out fast 2 times on `#g-plus` the Jquery runs it 4 times as in `show,hide,show,hide` and it looks retarded when it happens

How can i avoid this issue?

Comment: You're looking for `$.hover()` - https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: You should use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseleave`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is [.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop the previous animation

```js
function Gbox() {
    $("#g-box").hide();
}
Gbox();
$("#g-plus").hover(function () {
    $("#g-box").stop().show(400);
}, function () {
    $("#g-box").stop().hide(400);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="g-plus">g-plus</button>
<div id="g-box">g-box</div>
```

Note: You can use [.hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) as a short cut to register the mouseenter and mouseleave handlers

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#g-plus").hover(function () {
    $("#g-box").show(400);  
},function () {
    $("#g-box").hide(400);  
});
```

Comment: no +1 since this answer doesn't provide any explanation.

Comment: Uhm,this didn't fix my issue if i hover over your script fast in and out it does the same exact thing different method same issue